# How is this derived class abstract?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, virtual, abstract-class

So I have an abstract base class, Collection. I understand that it is abstract because it declares at least one pure virtual function.

I have a subclass of Collection, OrderedCollection, which declares those functions exactly in it's own header file. I then define those exact same functions in OrderedCollection's Source file.

Here is the code:

Class Collection.h

```
class Collection {

public:
virtual Collection& add(int i, int index) = 0;  //pure virtual
virtual Collection& remove(int i) = 0;  //pure virtual
virtual Collection& operator=(const Collection& other)=0;   //pure virtual
virtual int& operator[](int i) = 0; //pure virtual

Collection& iterate(void (*pFunc)());       //Function takes pointer to     function as argument
bool contains(int i);

virtual Collection& copy();


virtual ~Collection();

int size() { return size; }
int capacity() { return capacity; }

//virtual void swap(Collection& other);

protected:
Collection(){}

std::vector collectionVec;
int size;
int capacity;
};
```

Derived class OrderedCollection.h:

```
class OrderedCollection : public Collection
{
public:
OrderedCollection& add(int i, int index);
OrderedCollection& remove(int i);
OrderedCollection& operator=(const OrderedCollection& other);
int& operator[](int i);

OrderedCollection();
//OrderedCollection::OrderedCollection(int pFirst, int pLast, int pSize, int     pCapacity, std::vector<int> passedVec);

//OrderedCollection(const OrderedCollection& other);    //Copy constructor 

virtual ~OrderedCollection();

virtual OrderedCollection& copy(OrderedCollection& passedCollection);

protected:
//int* first;
//int* last;

int first;
int last;

OrderedCollection& grow();      //Utility Function
};
```

aaand OrderedCollection.cpp:

```
#include "OrderedCollection.h"

OrderedCollection& OrderedCollection::add(int i, int index){
if(size == capacity){       //If vector is full

}

return *this;
}

OrderedCollection& OrderedCollection::remove(int i){

if(first <= last){
    for(int j = first; j <= last; j++){
        if(collectionVec.at(j) == i){
            collectionVec.erase(j);
            last--;
        }
    }
}
/*for(int j = 0; j < collectionVec.size(); j++){
if(collectionVec.at(j) == i)

} */

return *this;
 }

OrderedCollection& OrderedCollection::operator=(const OrderedCollection& other){


if (this != &other) // protect against invalid self-assignment
{
    // 1: allocate new memory and copy the elements
    std::vector<int> *new_vector = new std::vector<int>(other.capacity);
    std::copy(other.collectionVec, other.collectionVec + other.capacity,     new_vector);

    // 2: deallocate old memory
    collectionVec.clear();


    // 3: assign the new memory to the object
    collectionVec = *new_vector;
    size = other.size;      //wtf
    capacity = other.capacity;      //wtf

    delete new_vector;
}
// by convention, always return *this
return *this;


}

int& OrderedCollection::operator[](int i){      //is return type correct? It makes     more sense to have a return type of int or int&, right?

int temp = 0;

if(first <= last){
    if(collectionVec.at(first + i) != NULL){    //Need to redo this
        return collectionVec.at(first + i);
    }
}
return temp;
}

OrderedCollection::OrderedCollection() : Collection()
{
//first = &collectionVec.at(2);
//last = &collectionVec.at(1);

//Crossed at construction
first = 2;
last = 1;
}



OrderedCollection::~OrderedCollection(void)
{
//first = NULL;
//last = NULL;
collectionVec.clear();
}

OrderedCollection& OrderedCollection::grow(){

    int newFirst = capacity / 2;
    std::vector<int> *new_vector = new std::vector<int>(2 * capacity);
    std::copy(collectionVec, collectionVec+size, new_vector->begin() + newFirst);       //Want to return iterator pointing to 
    collectionVec = new_vector;
    first = newFirst;
    last = first + size;
    capacity = collectionVec.size;

    delete new_vector;

    return *this;
}

OrderedCollection& OrderedCollection::copy(OrderedCollection& passedCollection){
OrderedCollection* temp =  new OrderedCollection()   //ERROR is here. VS highlights constructor method

return *this;
}
```

Now the issue comes when I am trying to create either a value identifier of type OrderedCollection within this last copy() here. As I understand it, I shouldn't be allowed to do this if the class is abstract (so clearly it is abstract, also VS tells me so). But there is another issue; I get the same error when I try to create a new OrderedCollection object and assigning it to temp. The above intialization is fine according VS (no complaints from the IDE, although it doesnt help me any). But I can't figure out why it's regarding this class as abstract.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this should cover all of the bases in making sure that this derived class is NOT abstract..

- There are no pure virtual functions declared within the derived class
- All functions that were pure virtual in the base class, have been overridden in the derived class.
- All of the overridden functions match the relevant function argument signature & return type, as originally declared in the base class.

The error exactly is, Error: object of abstract class type "OrderedCollection" is not allowed... And this is when I try to assign a pointer object to a new instance of OrderedCollection within this copy() method at the bottom.

Let me post my Collection.cpp file below:

```
#include "Collection.h"


Collection::Collection()
{
size = 0;
capacity = 4;
collectionVec.resize(capacity);
}


Collection::~Collection()
{

}

Collection& Collection::iterate(void (*pFunc)()){       

return *this;
}


bool contains(int i){


return true;
}
```

Edit: Added Collection.cpp file and updated some fixes I've made in regards to mismatching function parameters.

Comment: Which `Collection` methods do you implement in `Collection.cpp`?

Comment: Updated post with the .cpp file now. Also fixed some parameter mismatching.

Comment: You are not implementing the `Collection& copy()` method, see my answer.

Comment: Are you really posting your actual code, and the entire compiler error? Because this code has a lot more errors than that in it, and when VS reports an issue with an abstract class instantiation, it typically tells you exactly what you didn't override.

Comment: I tried to compile your code and I got a million errors

Comment: Having a pure virtual assignment operator is *extremely* unusual (like in "I have never seen that ever before"). What is the intention of using that here?

Comment: @JasonD & @ billz...I know I'm not at a point where I can compile yet. I'm still writing this code pretty early on. I've just noticed that when i was trying to define this copy() method I can't make a local OrderedCollection instance in copy() and I can't figure out why... I don't doubt that there are a million compile errors. Any idea the specific issue I brought up is occuring? Also, I've mentioned what VS spits back at me when trying to create this local OrderedCollection and it simply mentions that it is currently reading OrderedCollection as abstract, which it can't create an object.

Comment: @Bo Persson - This is an assignment for school. The project guideline states that the assignment operator must be pure virtual. I agree that it is strange.

Comment: It's giving you that error because the class is still abstract. You haven't overridden all the pure-virtuals, because you changed the argument type to at least one of them.

Comment: @Bo Persson: Taken from my assignment sheet:  Deferred
functions are called pure virtual member functions and are denoted by the =0 syntax in the function
declaration appearing in the class deﬁnition. Your abstract Collection class will defer the deﬁnition of
functions add(), remove(), the assignment operator operator=(), and the indexing operator operator[]().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
virtual Collection& operator=(const Collection& other)=0;
```

is not being overridden in the child class, because:

```
OrderedCollection& operator=(OrderedCollection& other);
```

Has a different signature.

The difference is not just the 'const', but the actual type. The overridden class must also take a Collection, and not the derived OrderedCollection.

Comment: Yeah, I actually just noticed this and changed it, but there are still issues.

Comment: The error exactly is, Error: object of abstract class type "OrderedCollection" is not allowed... And this is when I try to assign a pointer object to a new instance of OrderedCollection within this copy() method at the bottom.

Comment: I've updated my answer, as you still haven't quite corrected this problem.

Comment: Fixing the `const` in the signature doesn't help, as the assignment operator does not override the virtual operator of the base class (as it still has a different signature). So the derived class is still abstract. The question is - Why do you have a virtual operator in the base class?

Comment: @BoPersson I said he needed fix both the const and the *type*. If you do that, it overrides the base and stops the class being abstract.

Comment: One problem is that if the signature matches the base class operator, it is no longer the default assignment operator for the derived class, so the compiler will create one (that again calls the base class operator). I think the real problem is why the heck do we have a pure virtual operator in the base class?

Comment: @BoPersson Yeah, but that ends up with a link-time error rather than the abstract class error. Yes, there are lots of other issues with this code and I have no idea what the intention really is. However if the question is "why is this still abstract" - it's because of this function signature mismatch.

Comment: That was the problem, JasonD. So whenever I want to allow for polymorphism within my code, I must make the inherited virtual member functions have the EXACT same name and argument signature? In that case, it must also be a good idea (when defining the derived class' inherited member functions) to make all parameters passed as reference parameters/pointer parameters? So that no slicing occurs and I don't lose the information about that passed object.